# How to loop through an array of lists, check an element within each list and compare to a value and if it matches the value return the key

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, dictionary

I have an array holding hundreds of arrays, I am trying to loop through each array and test an element within each array to see if it exists in a dictionary. If so return the key that matches value. Here is where I am stuck. Heres what I am trying to accomplish.

```
dictionary = {'Bob' : '1', 'John' : '2', 'Andy': '3'}
list = [['5','2019','$50'],['1','2019','$50'],['5','2018','$50']

with open('C:/...','w',newline='') as f:
    fieldName = ['ID','Name','Price']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldName)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in list:
        if i[0] in dictionary.values():
            writer.writerow({'ID' : i[0], 'Name' : *DictionaryKey*, 'Price' : i[2]})
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: You should'nt use `list` as a variable's name, as it's a reserved keyword in python

Comment: Also, consider using `'w+'` as mode to open your file, it will take care of creating the file if it does not already exist.

Comment: the if statement inside the loop, through each loop check the first element in each list and if its in the dictionary values, return the key. So the output for the second loop should be ID: 1 Name: Bob

Comment: I would, if possible, restructure your dict so the ID ```(1, 2, 3 ...)``` is the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question:

```
dictionary = {'1' : 'Bob', '2' : 'John', '2': 'Andy'}
my_list = [['5','2019','$50'],['1','2019','$50'],['5','2018','$50']]

with open('C:/...','w',newline='') as f:
fieldName = ['ID','Name','Price']
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldName)
writer.writeheader()
for i in list:
  for key, value in dictionary:
      if i[0] == key:
           writer.writerow({'ID' : i[0], 'Name' : key, 'Price': i[2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a wrong use of your dictionnay by searching the key from the value: it should be the opposite. Plus there could be more than one keys corresponding to that value.

Your code should be on this tmeplate:

```
dictionary = {'1': 'Bob', '2': 'John', '3': 'Andy'}
my_list = [['5','2019','$50'],['1','2019','$50'],['5','2018','$50'] # do not use 'list' as variable name

with open('C:/...','w+',newline='') as f:
    fieldNames = ['ID','Name','Price']  
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldNames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for id_, year, price in my_list:
        if id_ in dictionary.values():
            writer.writerow({'ID' : id_, 'Name' : dictionary[id_], 'Price' : price})
```